# How to save pictures from URL to disk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to download pictures from a URL, like: http://trinity.e-stile.ru/ and save images to a directory like "C:\pickaxe\pictures". It is important to use Nokogiri.

I read similar questions on this site, but I didn't find how it works and I didn't understand the algorithm.

1. I wrote the code where I parse the URL and put parts of the webpage source code with "img" tag into a links object:

   ```
   require 'nokogiri'
   require 'open-uri'

   PAGE_URL="http://trinity.e-stile.ru/"
   page=Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))   #parsing into object
   links=page.css("img") #object with html code with img tag
   puts links.length # it is 24 images on this url
   puts
   links.each{|i| puts i } #it looks like: <img border="0" alt="" src="/images/kroliku.jpg"> 
   puts
   puts
   links.each{|link| puts link['src'] } #/images/kroliku.jpg
   ```

   What method is used to save pictures after grabbing the HTML code?
2. How can I put the images into a directory on my disk?

I changed the code, but it has an error:

```
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
```

This is the code now:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'

LOCATION = 'pics'
if !File.exist? LOCATION         # create folder if it is not exist
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.mkpath LOCATION
end

#PAGE_URL = "http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/files/hello-webpage.html"
#PAGE_URL="http://trinity.e-stile.ru/"
PAGE_URL="http://www.youtube.com/"
page=Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))   
links=page.css("img")

links.each{|link| 
    Net::HTTP.start(PAGE_URL) do |http|
      localname = link.gsub /.*\//, '' # left the filename only
      resp = http.get link['src']
      open("#{LOCATION}/#{localname}", "wb") do |file|
        file.write resp.body
      end
    end
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. The only thing left is to store files. Let’s do it.

```
LOCATION = 'C:\pickaxe\pictures'
if !File.exist? LOCATION         # create folder if it is not exist
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.mkpath LOCATION
end

require 'net/http'
.... # your code with nokogiri etc.
links.each{|link| 
    Net::HTTP.start(PAGE_URL) do |http|
      localname = link.gsub /.*\//, '' # left the filename only
      resp = http.get link['src']
      open("#{LOCATION}/#{localname}", "wb") do |file|
        file.write resp.body
      end
    end
end
```

That’s it.

Comment: I changed the code, Thank you, but it has an error:`initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Comment: I tried that..it switches another error:/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - www.youtube.com (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: I kinda lost in your explanations. Are you on windows (because of “save images to directory like that: C:\pickaxe\pictures” or on ×nix because of “/home/action/.parts...”? It looks like the host you use to run the code does not have internet access. The error you got means actually “DNS failed.”

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell.I work on Nitrous Web box(https://www.nitrous.io/), because nokogiri doesn't work correctly on my PC(Windows 7).The box is based on Linux with installed developing studio.But I think Internet works, because I parsed webpages succesfully...

Comment: Yeah, probably I misspelled “DNS problem” as “lack of internet access.” :) Anyway, the problem is with address resolving, from now on you are to try smth like `host www.youtube.com` fro mteh command line on your nitrous to undersatnd what’s happening on there.

Comment: In console I type:action@black-dragonstone-14-147675:~/tutorial1/Scripts(master*)$ host www.youtube.com  and what it shows: www.youtube.com is an alias for youtube-ui.l.google.com.

Comment: That’s it? It must than print a list of IPs. If it does not, your DNS is configured not properly. Anyway, this has nothing to do with both ruby and original question.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it on Linux virtual machine.Thank you very much!I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Rather than use Net::HTTP, use OpenURI to retrieve the image. OpenURI handles binary just fine, and is smart enough to deal with redirects, unlike Net::HTTP which will require additional code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct version:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


LOCATION = 'pics'
if !File.exist? LOCATION         # create folder if it is not exist
    require 'fileutils'
    FileUtils.mkpath LOCATION
end

#PAGE_URL="http://trinity.e-stile.ru/"
PAGE_URL="http://www.youtube.com/"

page=Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL)) 
links=page.css("img")

links.each{|link|
  uri = URI.join(PAGE_URL, link['src'] ).to_s # make absolute uri
  localname=File.basename(link['src'])
   File.open("#{LOCATION}/#{localname}",'wb') { |f| f.write(open(uri).read) }
  }
```

Comment: Don't do `link.gsub /.*\//, ''`. Use `File.basename` to extract just the filename: `File.basename('http://a.com/path/baz.jpg') # => "baz.jpg"`. Also, OpenURI is smarter than Net::HTTP, so use it instead.

Comment: I modified the code by your advice, now it works correct!Thank you!